# Product representation of $(2n)!$?

Tags: factorial

I know that $n!:=\prod_{k=1}^nk$. Would it just be $(2n)!:=\prod_{k=1}^n2k$ or  $(2n)!:=\prod_{k=1}^{2n}k$

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one. The first one is $n!2^n$.

Comment: So $(2n)!:=\prod_{k=1}^{2n}k$ would be correct, thanks!

Comment: Hi, in addition: $\frac{\prod_{k=1}^nn}{\prod_{k=1}^{2n}k}$ Can u simplify that expression?

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic That's $\frac{n^n}{(2n)!}$, unless you meant the numerator to be $\prod_{k=1}^n k$, in which case it would be $\frac{n!}{(2n)!}$. Either way, there's little scope for further tidying.

Answer (score 2):

Let us write them out:

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}k=1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot\ldots\cdot n=n!$$

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}2k=2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot\ldots\cdot 2n=2^nn!$$

$$\prod_{k=1}^{2n}k=1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n)=(2n)!$$

Comment: Can u somehow simplify $$\frac{\prod_{k=1}^nn}{\prod_{k=1}^{2n}k}$$ Is threre any rule?